# Raspberry Pi Camera Taking Takes Blurry Pictures

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam

I just got a camera for my raspberry pi 3, more specifically the Arducam 5 Megapixels 1080p Sensor ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B012V1HEP4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012V1HEP4)) link for clarification. After having some issue getting the camera to detect, I was finally able to take a picture and they came out blurry. I don't believe it is a focus issue are everything seems blurry regardless of distance from the camera. 
Images for reference:
[image]
[image]
When I open the image through the pi's gui it says that the image is 2592x1944. I'm not very familiar with cameras either so if its something related to the camera itself please explain in detail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's impossible to rule out all other possibilities, I suspect the issue is simply that your camera is out of focus. It was the issue in my case, and it's a well-known problem - or fact, if you prefer: the cameras are shipped with an odd focus plane setting. Re-focusing is what you should try first. [Here's a how-to-do-it link](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/fixing-blurry-focus-on-some-raspberry-pi-camera-v2-models), and there are many others available for the cost of a Google search.

If re-focusing doesn't cure the issue, let us know.

Comment: I tried using the method described in your link but could not get the lens to budge even an inch. I found myself starting to scrap up the lens so I decided to stop that method. I've found this tool on Thingiverse that I will try out. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1574661

Comment: Yes, it can be incredibly stubborn. And since it's plastic, you have to be careful about applying too much force, or in the wrong place. If you can inspect the lens under a magnifying glass, it may help you see the tabs that rotate the lens.   It does rotate, unless your lens was defective, so be persistent.

Comment: @S.Landerkin: It's just occurred to me that you may not have received the comment I posted a couple of days ago as I didn't put your handle in it.

Comment: thanks for the comments! I ended up getting it to work with your help, a shame that it takes so much effort to get it right though, it's so fragile it had me nervous the whole time. Again, much thanks!